# Laplacian of a composition of functions related to the gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Is there a place I can read the proof of ??

$$\Delta(\alpha\ \circ \ f ) = (\alpha''\ \circ \ f)||\nabla f||^2 + (\alpha'\ \circ \ f)\ \Delta f $$

$$\alpha:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$$ and $$ f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$$

I tried to do it by myself like $$\Delta(\alpha\ \circ \ f ) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial^2(\alpha\ \circ \ f )}{\partial x_i^2} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left( \alpha'\ \circ \ f \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}  \right) $$

But I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right way, you get the result bij applying Leibniz rule

$$ \sum_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} (\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}) = \sum_{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} (\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y}) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} +\sum_{i} ( \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x_i}) .$$

Applying the chain rule in the first term once more yields

$$ \sum_i(\frac{\partial ^2\alpha}{ \partial y^2})\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} +\sum_{i} ( \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x_i}).$$

So this is nothing other than

$$\frac{\partial ^2\alpha}{ \partial y^2}\Vert{\nabla f}\Vert ^2 + \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y} \Delta f. $$

Comment: I'm not sure, but did you missed the $\circ $ symbol? I mean, we should arrived to $(\alpha\ \circ\ f)\||\nabla f\||^2 + (\alpha' \ \circ\  f)\Delta f$

Comment: I have seen the idea, thanks!

Comment: Indeed the $\alpha$ (and derivatives) is always evaluated at f(x). I did make that implicit to lighten the notation a bit